# UITableView sections text alignment

Tags: iphone, objective-c

can someone help me with text alignment to the right in my uitableview sections ?

the defult alignment is left.
if the only way is to build custom header i will appreciate for code example.

Comment: Is there a good reason for doing so? In most cases it's best to stick with the system-defined way of laying things out. The users are used to it and don't get confused...

Comment: the application is in hebrew so in hebrew the default is right alignment

Comment: Right, that's a good reasons. Are there any other applications that exist in hebrew? Do they right-aling the labels as well?

Answer (score 2):

try with this

```
 -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    //create a uitextfield and set font you want in 
    return uitextfield ;
 }
```

it seems working for me.

Comment: UILabel makes more sense imho :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignRight;
```

to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

As long as you are using `cell.textLabel.text`, and not the deprecated `cell.text` to set the text of the cell, this should work.

edit:

Sorry, I didn't catch that you were trying to do this with the section headers. I think you're going to have to roll your own header views, and return them using the UITableView delegate method `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;`

Could take some work to get them to look like the default ones. Here is an example of someone describing how to theme the section headers: http://iphoneinaction.manning.com/iphone_in_action/2009/07/beauti.html

Comment: this will change the text in the cells what i am talking is the sections text between the cells.

Answer (score -1):

try this it is suitable for right to left languages

```
-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UILabel *lab = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex: section] valueForKey:kSectionTitleKey]; 
    lab.Text = @"right to left alignment text";

    lab.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    return lab.text;   
}
```

as you see in code this is the only way to align text from right to left, create a custom label, set its text property and alight the label to the right.